# I'm trying to make a tool in which you can input an IP address

Tags: java

I am trying to make an InetAddress object by entering an IP address with the line

```
InetAddress inetAddress=InetAddress.getByAddress(1.1.1.1); //random IP address for this post
```

As far as I can understand from oracle's website, this is how it should look but I get an error with the whole line underlined red and it says

"')' expected

incompatible types: double cannot be converted to byte[]"

any suggestions as to how to fix this? am I entering the IP address wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's expecting the address as a `byte[]`. Try:

```
InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{1,1,1,1})
```

Comment: Or `InetAddress.getByName("1.1.1.1")`.